# where can I set up character encoding in WSO2 EI

Tags: wso2

I'm new to WSO2,
In the WSO2 ESB profile, I tried to send a message like this:
`{"name":"中国"}`
but after proxy service and in my back-end service it printed:
`{"name":"???"}`

it also appeared both in API, when I debug the api, I can see the payload as already unreadable.
So I think I must set up character encoding before the payload coming in. But where can I do this?

Can you help me?

Comment: @SachiDangalla can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the following (as suggested in [this blog](http://ajanthane.blogspot.com/2016/11/how-to-overwrite-character-set-encoding.html)):

`<property name="CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>`

Comment: I have tried this,  but it did't work. In the log which printed in the wso2 EI I could see the message's charset was right, but in my back-end service the charset was still wrong. So I think I must forget something, by the way, I counld not find the property which named "CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING" in property mediator, so I add a new property and named it "CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING", this would be the reason that the charset was still wrong. So how could I do?